# Phong lighting model - R vector

Tags: lighting

In Phong lighting model a vector R is used to calculate the spectral component of light. The equation used to obtain it is

```
R = 2(N•L)N - L
```

I can't understand why we use this equation. Could someone give me a demonstration of how we obtain this equation?

Comment: For anybody arriving here from a search, I have a more detailed explanation of the derivation of the formula in question - without requiring prior knowledge of vector algebra - on the math sister site: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4335556/6928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is a consequence of the symmetry of the reflection of the light about the normal:

[image]

We know from the [law of reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Laws_of_reflection) that the angle between `R` and `N` is the same as the one between `L` and `N`. Therefore it's also clear that:

```
R•N = L•N (assume all are unit vectors)
```

From symmetry, it's also evident that

```
R - (R•N)N = - (L - (L•N)N)
```

Now we can replace `(R•N)N` with `(L•N)N` from the previous equation. So we have:

```
R - (L•N)N = - (L - (L•N)N)
```

Adding `(L•N)N` to both sides gives:

```
R = - (L - (L•N)N) + (L•N)N
  = - L + (L•N)N + (L•N)N
  = 2(L•N)N - L
```